# EE 2.9 notification email from DevDemon Forms bug

Tags: forms, devdemon

I think DevDemon Forms got the same issue I experienced (now fixed) with FireMail (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/firemail/viewthread/13824).

All the notification emails created by DevDemon Forms, starting with 
**{!-- ra:00000000545df7cc00000000xxxxxxxx --}**

This all happened after upgrading to EE 2.9. We are on DevDemon Forms v3.4.11

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this error on Forms? I am having the same problem as well

Comment: May be related to this bug: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20552/snippets-and-early-parsed-vars-appended-by-garbage-when-wrapped-in-plugin

Comment: DevDemon have now fixed this error